# React js: Invariant Violation: processUpdates() when rendering a table with a different number of child rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error when my react component is re-rendered after a click event:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 2 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated ...
```

This only happens when my table has a different number of rows than the previously rendered version. For example:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

React = require('react');

var _ = require("underscore");

var testComp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return { 
      collapsed: false
    };
  },

  handleCollapseClick: function(){
    this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed});
  },

  render: function() {

    var rows = [
      <tr onClick={this.handleCollapseClick}><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>
    ];

    if(!this.state.collapsed){
      rows.push(<tr><th>Row1 1</th><th>Row1 2</th><th>Row1 3</th></tr>);
    }

    rows.push(<tr><th>Footer 1</th><th>Footer 2</th><th>Footer 3</th></tr>);

    return  <div>
                <table>
                    {rows}
                </table>
            </div>
  }

});

module.exports = testComp
```

If I render different content, but with the same number of rows, I don't get the error, so if I update the if statement to:

```
if(!this.state.collapsed){
  rows.push(<tr><th>Row1 1</th><th>Row1 2</th><th>Row1 3</th></tr>);
}else{
  rows.push(<tr><th>Row2 1</th><th>Row2 2</th><th>Row2 3</th></tr>);
}
```

... everything works.

Do I need to force react to re-render the entire component in this case, instead of just the 'changed' elements?

Comment: This could be because you are not giving the elements inside the array unique `key`s. See http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html , dynamic children.

Comment: Even with keys added I see the same result...

Comment: Actually, adding keys means that even when using the same number of elements I still get the above error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., ...$110): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should read the full error message (at least that's what I am seeing):

> Unable to find child 2 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated **(e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a `<tbody>`** when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using non-SVG elements in an  parent.

Every table needs a `<tbody>` element. If it doesn't exist, the browser will add it. However, React doesn't work if the DOM is manipulated from the outside.

Related: [Removing row from table results in TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21594009/218196)

Comment: Ah OK. When React first renders without a tbody, the browser then inserts it. On re-render there is a discrepancy between what React wants to render and what is in the DOM, hence the error. Thanks, day 2 using React here...

Comment: Yep, Chrome especially will close tags, remove p tags that are illegally nested in other p tags, all kinds of things that can really confuse you sometimes...

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this when dealing with *p* tags. I had nested paragraphs within paragraphs.

To resolve the problem I replaced the wrapping *p* element with a *div* element.

Before:

```
render: function render() {
    return (
        <p>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
        </p>
    );
}
```

After:

```
render: function render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: ah this looks like the issue I'm having.. but without seeing the surrounding code your example doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Those tags should be output by a render function in a React component. @krivar, I updated my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: You can't have p tags within p tags because it's illegal. Browsers "fix" it for you

Answer (score 0):

For people who are using react-templates:

You have to generate the `<tbody>` tag in the .jsx file. If you only add it in the .rt file you still get the error message.

```
this.tbody = <tbody>{tablerows}</tbody> // - in .jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case the fix is to remove spaces in Table render from

```
<tbody> {rows} </tbody>
```

to

```
<tbody>{rows}</tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is with using the `<th>` tag in multiple rows. `<th>` is reserved for the header row. Try replacing it with `<td>` everywhere except in the first row. Also you should wrap the header in a `<thead>` tag and the rest in a `<tbody>` tag:

```
var header = [
  <tr onClick={this.handleCollapseClick}><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>
];

var body = [];
if(!this.state.collapsed){
  body.push(<tr><td>Row1 1</td><td>Row1 2</td><td>Row1 3</td></tr>);
}

body.push(<tr><td>Footer 1</td><td>Footer 2</td><td>Footer 3</td></tr>);

 return <div>
     <table>
         <thead>{header}</thead>
         <tbody>{body}</tbody>
     </table>
 </div>;
```

Comment: You can use `<th>` wherever you want, technically. React does not enforce semantics.

Comment: Yes, apologies. I forgot about the tags inbetween, I updated the answer