# ReactJs "Invariant violation..." Classic react issue

Tags: reactjs

This is a typical react issue but I kinda don't know how to handle it.
I just want to render my table lines dynamically but I get the error:"
"Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 2 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,

, or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `.2.1.0`."

I understand react is not finding the right DOM stuff but how to handle that ? Thanks in advance !

```
<div className="panel-body" style={panelstyle}>
              <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <thread>
                  <th> Currency </th>
                  <th> Amount </th>
                  <th> Issuer </th>
                  <th> Limit </th>
                  <th> Limit Peer </th>
                  <th> No-Ripple </th>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.ripplelines[this.address] ?

                              this.state.ripplelines[this.address].lines.map(function(line,i) {

                            return      (<tr>
                                          <td> USD </td>
                                          <td> 1500 </td>
                                          <td> raazdazdizrjazirazrkaẑrkazrâkrp </td>
                                          <td> 1000000000 </td>
                                          <td> 0 </td>
                                          <td> True </td>
                                        </tr>)       
                            ;
                        })             
                  : ""}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the full code of the component?

Protip (unrelated): you can use `{condition && element}` instead of `{condition ? element : ''}` as React doesn't render the value `false`. See [False in JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html).

Comment: this is the full component, add return( before and ) at the end of this code. Thanks for the condition tip but this is  not helping my problem (could use this tip anyway thanks)

Comment: Also, a few errors I've noticed: `<thread>` should be `<thead>` (same for the closing tag), your `<th>` elements should be inside a `<tr>` element, and you should pass a unique key to each of your table rows (`<tr key={i}>` will do if you don't plan on reordering them).

Comment: thanks that's useful bot not really helping this specific problem

Comment: Could you provide us with the source/repo of the `Table` component?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the other advises!

Comment: @FrançoisRichard hello, did you find any solution to this problem? thanks, Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an answer here: [React js: Invariant Violation: processUpdates() when rendering a table with a different number of child rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689900/react-js-invariant-violation-processupdates-when-rendering-a-table-with-a-di)

Just prepare your rows before rendering!

```
render:
 var rows = [];
      if(this.state.ripplelines[this.address] ) {
        _.each(this.state.ripplelines[this.address].lines, function(line) {
           rows.push(                   <tr>
                                          <td> somestuff!</td>

                                        </tr>)
        }); 
      }
return (
    <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                    <thead>
                      <th> Currency </th>
                      <th> Amount </th>
                      <th> Issuer </th>
                      <th> Limit </th>
                      <th> Limit Peer </th>
                      <th> No-Ripple </th>
                    </thead>     
                    <tbody>
                      {rows}    
                    </tbody>
              </Table>
)
```

Comment: yes so your component are unique and you avoid the error. You could use .map also it would work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using **Immutable** with **React.js**:

I was getting the same error even with proper `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. Turns out I was using `Immutable.List()` to store my `<tr>` elements. Converting that to an array via `.toArray()` solved this error.