# Resct JS react-draggable-tab - Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, playframework, draggable

I have a problem while integrating react-draggable-tab (https://github.com/georgeOsdDev/react-draggable-tab) into my React JS/Play Framework application.

I have rewrite code example from the app.js (https://github.com/georgeOsdDev/react-draggable-tab/blob/develop/example/app.js) in the project example directory into my .jsx component:

```
'use strict';

import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import ContentWrapper from '../Layout/ContentWrapper';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Dropdown, Panel} from 'react-bootstrap';

import spdf from "simple-react-pdf";

import PanelsRun from './Panels.run';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import {Dialog, FlatButton, Menu, MenuItem, TextField} from 'material-ui';


import Tabs from 'react-draggable-tab';
import Tab from 'react-draggable-tab';


import DynamicTabContent from 'react-draggable-tab';
import DynamicTabBadge from 'react-draggable-tab';


//allow react dev tools work
window.React = React;


const tabsClassNames = {
    tabWrapper: 'myWrapper',
    tabBar: 'myTabBar',
    tabBarAfter: 'myTabBarAfter',
    tab:      'myTab',
    tabTitle: 'myTabTitle',
    tabCloseIcon: 'tabCloseIcon',
    tabBefore: 'myTabBefore',
    tabAfter: 'myTabAfter'
};

const tabsStyles = {
    tabWrapper: {marginTop: '10px'},
    tabBar: {},
    tab:{},
    tabTitle: {},
    tabCloseIcon: {},
    tabBefore: {},
    tabAfter: {}
};


class CVs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let icon = (<image src='icon.png' style={{height:'13px'}}/>);
        let fonticon = (<icon className='icon-html5'/>);
        let badge = (<DynamicTabBadge />);

        this.state = {
            tabs:[
                (<Tab key={'tab0'} title={'unclosable tab'} disableClose={true} >
                    <div>
                        <h1>This tab cannot close</h1>
                    </div>
                </Tab>),
                (<Tab key={'tab1'} title={'1stTab'} beforeTitle={icon} >
                    <div>
                        <h1>This is tab1</h1>
                    </div>
                </Tab>),
                (<Tab key={'tab2'} title={'2ndTab Too long Toooooooooooooooooo long'} beforeTitle={fonticon} >
                    <div>
            <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            </pre>
                    </div>
                </Tab>),
                (<Tab key={'tab3'} title={'Dynamic tab'} afterTitle={badge}>
                    <DynamicTabContent/>
                </Tab>)
            ],
            badgeCount: 0
        };
    }

    handleTabSelect(e, key, currentTabs) {
        console.log('handleTabSelect key:', key);
        this.setState({selectedTab: key, tabs: currentTabs});
    }

    handleTabClose(e, key, currentTabs) {
        console.log('tabClosed key:', key);
        this.setState({tabs: currentTabs});
    }

    handleTabPositionChange(e, key, currentTabs) {
        console.log('tabPositionChanged key:', key);
        this.setState({tabs: currentTabs});
    }

    handleTabAddButtonClick(e, currentTabs) {
        // key must be unique
        const key = 'newTab_' + Date.now();
        let newTab = (<Tab key={key} title='untitled'>
            <div>
                <h1>New Empty Tab</h1>
            </div>
        </Tab>);
        let newTabs = currentTabs.concat([newTab]);

        this.setState({
            tabs: newTabs,
            selectedTab: key
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ContentWrapper>
                    <Tabs
                        tabsClassNames={tabsClassNames}
                        tabsStyles={tabsStyles}
                        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab ? this.state.selectedTab : "tab2"}
                        onTabSelect={this.handleTabSelect.bind(this)}
                        onTabClose={this.handleTabClose.bind(this)}
                        onTabAddButtonClick={this.handleTabAddButtonClick.bind(this)}
                        onTabPositionChange={this.handleTabPositionChange.bind(this)}
                        tabs={this.state.tabs}
                        shortCutKeys={
                  {
                    'close': ['alt+command+w', 'alt+ctrl+w'],
                    'create': ['alt+command+t', 'alt+ctrl+t'],
                    'moveRight': ['alt+command+tab', 'alt+ctrl+tab'],
                    'moveLeft': ['shift+alt+command+tab', 'shift+alt+ctrl+tab']
                  }
                }
                    />
            </ContentWrapper>
        );
    }
};



CVs.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default CVs;
```

The render method of the component above causes following exception:

```
app.js:1 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `CVs`.warning @ app.js:1

app.js:1 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `CVs`.
```

None of the following seem to apply to my case:
[Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Additionaly I provide files which may be helpful.

Main view:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, hashHistory, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import initTranslation from './components/Common/localize';
import initLoadCss from './components/Common/load-css';

import Base from './components/Layout/Base';
import BasePage from './components/Layout/BasePage';
import BaseHorizontal from './components/Layout/BaseHorizontal';

import SingleView from './components/SingleView/SingleView';
import SubMenu from './components/SubMenu/SubMenu';
import Candidates from './components/Candidates/Candidates';
import CVs from './components/CVs/CVs';


// Init translation system
initTranslation();
// Init css loader (for themes)
initLoadCss();


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

        <Route path="/" component={Base}>

            {/* Default route*/}
            <IndexRoute component={SingleView} />

            <Route path="singleview" component={SingleView}/>
            <Route path="submenu" component={SubMenu}/>
            <Route path="candidates" component={Candidates}/>
            <Route path="cvs" component={CVs}/>

        </Route>

        {/* Not found handler */}
        {/*<Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>*/}

    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "play-react-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Playframework + React Js + webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Nouhoum Traoré",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prestart": "bower install",
    "start": "npm install",
    "poststart": "gulp"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "play",
    "reactjs",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.4",
    "classnames": "2.2.5",
    "history": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.5.3",
    "react": "15.2.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.2.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^2.3.6",
    "react-dom": "15.2.1",
    "react-draggable-tab": "^0.7.0",
    "react-router": "2.5.2 ",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.23.0",
    "simple-react-pdf": "1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-require": "2.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.0.15",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-bundle-assets": "^2.27.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-expect-file": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-filter": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.8",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-html-prettify": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-ignore": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-jade": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-jsvalidate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^1.3.9",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rtlcss": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui": "0.15.2"
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help!