# React-router errors: Warning: React.createElement, Uncaught Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I got such an error when I try to use react-router:
[image]
Here's the code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Match } from 'react-router'
import Landing from './Landing'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

const App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className='app'>
          <Match exactly pattern='/' component={Landing} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
})

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Landing.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation'

const Landing = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <Navigation />
    )
  }
})

export default Landing
```

The Navigation.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import {Collapse, NavbarToggler, Navbar, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink} from 'reactstrap'

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }
  toggle () {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color='faded' light toggleable>
          <NavbarToggler right onClick={this.toggle} />
          <NavbarBrand href='/'>reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className='ml-auto' navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink tag={Link} to='https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap'>Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink tag={Link} to='https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap'>Github</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navigation
```

The reason I think the problem is in router is because without router it renders well.
From package.json:  **"react-router": "4.0.0-beta.4"**

Comment: How are you exporting your Landing component? Does it have a default export?

Comment: Yes, default. And I've read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string and still can't find the errror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohhh, that beta and apha's!! It's a good lesson for not using them, or if use then very cautious with that.
So the problem was that in the tutorial that I used was using "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.5", but I used latest version "react-router": "4.0.0-beta.4". So instead of

```
import { BrowserRouter, Match } from 'react-router'
```

I should use

```
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and instead of

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className='app'>
    <Match exactly pattern='/' component={Landing} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I should use

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className='app'>
     <Route exact pattern='/' component={Landing} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

After these changes - no errors were defined.

Answer (score 0):

Landing.js propably returniung undefined, so do you export Navigation?

You can try:

```
//Landing.js
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation'

const Landing = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(Navigation);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>Landing working</div>
    )
  }
})

export default Landing
```

Comment: well, you can try returning Landing in App.js, so you will know if the error is because of router or your component

Comment: oh, sorry... so problem is in router, im not really sure why are you using `BrowserRouter` and `Match` component. Im using `<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />` and it works fine.

Comment: I've post the answer in  fact - your last guessing was right