# react native createClass error

Tags: react-native

I have this codes:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  MapView,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var Weather = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <MapView style={styles.map}></MapView>
  }

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Weather', () => Weather);
```

I just want to test the map, however, when I run it, I got the error:

Seems you're trying to access 'react-native' package. Perhaps you meant to access 'React.createClass' from the 'react' package instead ?

I don' t see what's wrong with the above codes, can you help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing incorrectly. You need to also import React to be able to use React.createClass, right now you're naming React as the 'react-native' library:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  MapView,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} = ReactNative;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your import codes still same error message as Talor A sugestion

Comment: Yea, i posted on his comment but i'll post here too: If you're using RN version 0.44.0, MapView is no longer available. If that's not the issue, update your post with your code so we can see what you have.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes I am using RN 0.44...that' s the problem :( , I tried to replace MapView with some text output, the text display correctly, do you know if there is any alternative native map on 0.44 to replace the <mapView> or they just remove it completely ?

Comment: Ok, I have a look on the link.thanks all for your helps

Comment: I don't think you can use createClass anymore, you will have to use an es6 class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ES6 classes are the recommended way to create react components in React Native. to do that, your component should look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  MapView,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'

class Weather extends Component {
  render () {
    ...
  }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried ES6 classes, I have now the error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in...

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: If you're using RN version 0.44.0, MapView is no longer available