# React invariant error

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm running into the following error only when I test this in our staging environment, though the code runs without error when I run it locally.

`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

There are two ways I can get the view to load without triggering the error.

1. I remove the `onClick={handleClick}` prop on the `<Tabs />` styled-component
2. If I explicitly define the individual `<Tab />` components as `spans` i.e. `<span data-filter="yourTasks">Your Tasks</span>`

`List` component

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';

const List = ({ handleFiltering, listItems, match }) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    handleFiltering(e.target.dataset.filter);
  }

  return (
    <ListWrapper>
      <Tabs onClick={handleClick}>
        <Tab data-filter="yourTasks">Your Tasks</Tab>
        <Tab data-filter="allTasks">All Tasks</Tab>
        <Tab data-filter="assignedTasks">Assigned</Tab>
      </Tabs>

      { _.map(listItems, item => <ListItem key={item._id} item={item} /> )}
    </ListWrapper>
  );
}

const ListWrapper = styled.section`
  flex: 1;
`;

const Tabs = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const Tab = styled.span`
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
`;

export default List;
```

from parent `ListContainer` component where `handleFiltering` is defined

```
...

handleFiltering(filterType, list) {
  list = list || this.state.list;

  const filterTypes = {
    allTasks: () => list,
    yourTasks: () => (list.filter(item => item.assignedTo === this.userId)),
    assignedTasks: () => (list.filter(item => item.createdBy === this.userId)),
  }

  this.setState(() => {
    return { filteredList: filterTypes[filterType]() }
  });
}

...
```

I did run through the ["master" invariant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) with no luck.

Comment: Try pausing on caught exceptions and then digging around in the stack trace to see if you can find exactly which element ends up undefined. 
Maybe it's a minification problem if it only happens in your staging environment. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception

Comment: Try moving your styled component declarations above the component in which they are referenced.

Comment: @jadam This happens when there is a problem with your imports. Check this QA:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @RickJolly that was it. Must have been an issue during minification? Feel free to leave as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as Rick Jolly had mentioned in the comments, that the styled-components were defined after the component declaration.

I believe this is likely due to how things are being minified when bundled for prod/staging, but welcome more feedback there if someone knows more.

@rick-jolly, feel free to post as answer and I will attribute yours as the accepted solution.