# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) but it seems my problem is different (ie I don't think its an improperly destructured import)

This is the error I get. The files mentioned are deep in the react-native library, and unfortunately the message is not very informative.

> ExceptionsManager.js:73 Check your code at renderApplication.js:35.
>
> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>      built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>      but got: object. ExceptionsManager.js:65
>
> This error is located at:
>
> ```
> in RCTView (at View.js:71)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
> in RCTView (at View.js:71)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
> ```

The index.js below gives me the error, **but if I display directly my component by using the commented line instead to register, everything works as expected.**

index.js:

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {App} from './src/App';
import {Test} from './src/App';
//AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => Test);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', App);
```

./src/App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import reducer from './reducers/index'
import AppContainer from './containers/AppContainer'
import {  Text,  View} from 'react-native';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({predicate: (getstate, action) => __DEV__});

function ConfigureStore(initialState){
   const enhancer = compose(
     applyMiddleware(loggerMiddleware)
   );

   return createStore(reducer,initialState, enhancer);
  }

const store = ConfigureStore({});

export class Test extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text >
         xxx
         </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const App= () =>(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Test/>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)? Same symptoms. And it leads to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281#36796281)

Comment: Yes I did, and mentioned it in the very first sentence of my question! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your code to the following works correctly.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

`registerComponent` seems to expect a function that returns a component or stateless component, rather than contents of the component (JSX).

Comment: You're right, it works. Thanks a lot. That being said, App is already a function that returns a Provider component (ie export const App= () =>( .... So I don't understand why your suggestion works, but it certainly does !

Answer (score 0):

It's import problem. When I used:
in cart.js
`const CartItem = require("./cart-item");`
in cart-item.js
`export default CartItem`
I did have this problem, but when I change import:
in cart.js
`import CartItem from "../cart/cart-item";`
all works fine!