# Invariant Violation with only some Navigators (React-Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm running into some weird behaviors when trying to implement the Navigators from React-Navigation.

When trying out the simple "hello world" from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html...

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});
```

I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>   Check the render method of 'SceneView'.

The strange part is that while using the StackNavigator (and TabNavigator) give me the Invariant Violation, using a DrawerNavigator does not!

[This common fix (removing the braces in the import) gives a new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string):

> Object is not a function

[And the common fix to "Object is not a function" leads me back to where I started (adding braces to the import).](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/666)

I'm new to React-Native and not sure how to dive deeper into this problem, any help is appreciated!

-----**Edit**-----

I've downgraded my version of react-navigation to v1.5.5 and the original StackNavigator component works, so perhaps it's a compatibility issue with v2.0.1 and my environment.

Answer (score 3):

Check in package.json if you have the right `react` version for your `react-native`. For example,

```
"react": "16.4.0",
"react-native": "^0.53",
"react-navigation": "^2.0.4",
```

doesn't work for me, but

```
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.53",
"react-navigation": "^2.0.4",
```

works.

Comment: not sure why this isn't upvoted more. solved my problem

Comment: This is the most bizzare bug I have found which wasted 3 hours of my time. I had `"react": "^16.2.0"` in my `package.json` but realised it was resolving to `16.6.3` and was causing this error.

Rolling back to `"16.2.0"` fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found your problem. I think you're trying to follow the docs for the wrong version. I assume you're using V1 of React-Navigation.

You can view your current installed version by running "yarn list react-navigation" in your terminal in the project root.

V1 Docs: https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation.html

If I use the example from the link above everything works fine. Perhaps you could try that?

Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, shows me as having -react-navigation@2.0.1  
Trying to use the old "StackNavigator" gives me a warning that it is deprecated and to use "createStackNavigator" instead.