# Element type is invalid: expected a string & search input not filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have **two issues** with this code:

**First:**
I have the following error in the code: ***Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.***

***Check the render method of `App`.***

How do I fix this? You can find the error here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l5k6w5rqjl

**Second**, inside `<App/>`, on **line 49** `console.log(data.contents);` appears **undefined**. What is the problem here? Is this the reason for `<FileTree/>` not filtering correctly on search?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import SearchEngine from "./components/search_bar";
import { FileTree } from "./components/file_tree";
import { TextBox } from "./components/text_box";
import { data } from "./components/file_tree";

// Dummy data set
export const root = data[0];

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: "",
      root: root
    };

this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

  // Props from <TextBox/> to <App/>
  liftStateUp = data => {
    this.setState({ activeNode: data });
  };

  onSubmitSearch = (e, search) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tree = JSON.stringify(root); // always search full data tree
    tree = JSON.parse(tree); // JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse are
    console.log(tree);
    if (!search || search === "") {
      // if search is undefined, null or empty, set root to full data tree
      this.setState({ root: tree }); // state.root is filtered tree passed     to the FileTree component
  return;
} else {
  this.setState({
    root: this.filterTree(tree, search.toLowerCase())
  });
}
/* uncoment if you need to filter already filtered tree */
// tree = JSON.stringify(this.state.root);
// tree = JSON.parse(tree);
  };

  filterTree = (data, search) => {
    let children = data.contents;
    console.log(data.contents);

    if (!children || !children.length) {
      if (!data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
        data.remove = true;
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.filterTree(children[i], search);
        if (children[i].remove) {
          children.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      if (!children.length) {
        data.remove = true;
      }
    }
    return data;
  };

  onChange(data) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <SearchEngine
            className="form-control"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            onSubmitSearch={this.onSubmitSearch}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FileTree
            root={this.state.root}
            liftStateUp={this.liftStateUp}
            searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <TextBox content={this.state.activeNode} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: @Adelin How so?

Comment: It has 22 answers of similar error. Surely there's something that can hint you in the right direction from there.

Comment: @Adelin I tried from `import { FileTree } from "./components/file_tree";` to `import FileTree from "./components/file_tree";` and also changing the export inside file_tree.js. The error remains there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Changes:**

**1-** Add some code in directory.js file:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Directory = () => <div>Directry</div>;
```

**2-** You are not exporting the FileTree from `file_tree` file:

```
export class FileTree extends React.Component {....}
```

**3-** In search_bar file you are exporting the same component twice, once default and once named export, so remove the export keyword here:

`export class SearchEngine`

[Working Code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3knkv28q6)

Comment: Thank you! It was my silly distraction! Have you checked the `console.log(data.contents)` on line 49? If you check the console, `contents` is undefined. I can't seem to figure out why @Mayank Shukla

Comment: check this [**snippet**](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3knkv28q6), its array reference issue always create copy of the array then do the changes. let me know if this is not what you were talking about.

Comment: I completed the `Directory` code so it's possible to search. https://codesandbox.io/s/pw533yyxkx @Mayank Shukla

Comment: can you please explain more, what you are trying to achieve and the issue with the last link you sent in comment?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: http://storybooks.github.io/react-treebeard/ but instead the search input has a search button and filters the filetree below, showing you what you are looking for. @Mayank Shukla

Comment: check this [**snippet**](https://codesandbox.io/s/925rq1noky), hoping this will be final :P