# Unable to render the JSON object in a list from Github issues api

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
`import store from '../store/configureStore'; // ACTIONS

export const fetchIssues = () => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_ISSUE'
  };
};

export const fetchedIssues = (data) => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCHED_ISSUE',
    data
  };
};

export const error = () => {
  return {
    type: 'ERROR'
  };
};

export const thunkActionCreator = () => {
  store.dispatch(fetchIssues());
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/issues`)
    .then( (resp) => resp.json() )
    .then( (data) => dispatch(fetchedIssues(data)) )
    .catch( (err) => dispatch(error()) )
  };
};`

const initialState = {  // REDUCERS
  issues: [],
  isFetching: false,
  isFetched: false,
  isError: false
};

const asyncReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ISSUE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        isFetched: false,
        isError: false
      };
    case 'FETCHED_ISSUE':
      return {
        ...state,
        issues: action.data,
        isFetching: false,
        isFetched: true,
        isError: false
      };
    case 'ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        issues: [],
        isError: true,
        isFetched: false,
        isFetching: false
      };
  };
};

export default asyncReducer; // Reducers

import React from 'react';  // ISSUES COMPONENT
import { thunkActionCreator } from './actions/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import IssueLoader from './Loader';
import IssuesList from './IssuesList';

class Issues extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(thunkActionCreator());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.props.issue !== undefined && this.props.issue.isFetching ? <IssueLoader className='loader'/> : null}
        {this.props.issue !== undefined && this.props.issue.isFetched ? 
          this.props.issue.issues.map((issue) => <IssuesList data={issue}/>) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    issue: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Issues);

import React from 'react'; // ISSUES LIST COMPONENT
import {Image, List} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class IssuesList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    issue: state
  }
}

export default (mapStateToProps)(IssuesList);
```

I'm making a github issues page using react and redux and the api is returning a single array of 30 Objects and when I use map on the given array It is giving the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I've searched everything on stackoverflow, github but unable to find the solution. I'm attaching the pictures of my code please Help!!

Comment: please include code relevant to your question

Comment: I've added the code Please review it :)

Comment: Hi @HaroonAhmed, I've just added an answer to help you resolve the error you're getting - does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

This error may have something to do with your component or how you are importing rather than the api. Here is a previous answer to your question  [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: I'm unable to usnderstand what are you saying? Please elaborate

Comment: if you dont mind can I give you the link to the repository so you can check?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `IssuesList` is being exported for it's module incorrectly. I can't see why `mapStateToProps` is needed for `IssuesList` - based on your code, it would see `IssuesList` is really intended to display each issue item.

If you make the following adjustment to module where `IssuesList` is defined, your code should display a issue titles returned from the network request:

```
export default class IssuesList extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{ this.props.data.title }</h1>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaankk youu sooo much It worked but what's the difference between exporting like this way and the way I was doing? why that was giving error

Comment: Glad I could help you @HaroonAhmed ! The difference is that you original approach was passing the component to a locally declared function `mapStateToProps()` that just returned a JSON object (which is not what react is expecting). At that point you just want to export a component directly. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @HaroonAhmed if you've found this helpful please consider accepting :-)