# React-native - Application working on emulator but not in real devices

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

It's the first time I'm asking here. Been using `Stackoverflow` from a while but this time, I got stuck for a while for a important long-term school project. I'm also new with `React-native`.

I'm developping an application in `React-Native` on `Windows`, but this application works only on an `emulator` and not on a `real device` (tested on a Nexus 5X and a Google Pixel) with an unsigned generated `APK` and with developpement (câble and Metro bundler)

I checked many solutions here but it not seems to be an error of calls. The code is a bit fat so i can't leave all the code here, i neither have logs, but i can provide on demand (i don't know what could i provide)

Here's the error i'm always getting on devices :

[image]

Thanks in advance, this is really important :(

**EDIT :**
I just spotted the fact Metro Bundler aren't bundling (with a progress bar and delta) with the mobile device, but works with the emulator.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string

Comment: Did you try all the solutions mentioned in link which given by @Sateesh

Comment: Yes...!!! One of the solutions in the mentioned link worked for me when I was facing the same issue.

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara yes, i saw that and i checked but all seems to be ok, the problem is, i don't understand why this is working on emulator and not in device ? (metro bundler don't do anything with the device :()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the RN GitHub issues, are you sure that you're exporting your App?

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332#issuecomment-336925116

`class YourApp extends Component {` -> `export default class YourApp extends Component<{}> {`

If so, is it being registered in the correct way?
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('yourApp', () => App);`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer !
Yeah, every classes (including the main one) are exported with "export default", with `<{]>` after `Component`, i just separate the declaration of the class and his exportation.

`class YourApp extends React.Component<{}>` and `export default YourApp;`
Also yeah, its registered in the same way. :(