# How to fix Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-rails

I am trying to run ReactRails app and trying to run a very simple react-select component. However, in the same file if I print just a simple `h2` element it works but `<Select/>` doesn't work. It gives:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I am trying to use `react-select` component. I've installed it via `yarn add` command.

**User.jsx:**

```
var React = require("react")
var Select = require("react-select")
var PropTypes = require("prop-types")

// also tried these ->
// import React from 'react';
// import createClass from 'create-react-class';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import Select from 'react-select';


const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    /*
    return (
             <h2>THIS WORKS!</h2>
    )
    */



    return (
             <Select
                 value={selectedOption}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 options={options}
             />
    )

    // Doesn't work:
    // Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

  }
}
module.exports = User
```

I am very new to React world. What Am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Note: This did not solved my problem: [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: why you have you commented out `import Select....`?

Comment: I tried `import`-way and `var Select...` way. Both using `import` or `var` gives error. If I use "import" I get "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined" (Note the end undefined.)

Comment: Your import syntax was fine (as long as you're bundling your code). The rest of your code appeared to be fine as well, at first glance. Thinking maybe it's somewhere else in your app? Here's a quick and dirty working example https://codesandbox.io/s/zx45kql9q4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the module.exports plays with React. When I try your code with ES6 syntax it seems to work fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
```

and then using ES6 export instead of module.exports:

```
export default User;
```

The Select component doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: `export default User;`! Thanks!.