# React 16 context provider returning undefined when rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-context

I'm using React's new context api (v16.x).

I made a simple test application to ensure my understanding of it:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

const Child = () => (
  <MyContext.Consumer>
    {value => value}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
)

const Parent = () => (
  <MyContext.Provider value={"Working"}>
    <Child/>
  </MyContext.Provider>
)
```

This works fine, even with intermediary components between `<Parent>` and `<Child>`.

However, the component below produces the following error: *"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"* (note: I'm using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) library)

```
let NavigationPanel = (props) => (
  <DisabledContext.Provider value={props.disabled}>
    <InstructionsContext.Provider value={props.onOpenInstructions}>
      <Hidden mdUp><DrawerNavigationPanel data={props.data}/></Hidden>
      <Hidden smDown><StaticNavigationPanel data={props.data}/></Hidden>
    </InstructionsContext.Provider>
  </DisabledContext.Provider>
)
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: This is more likely related to your imports. Check out this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265067/6899860

Comment: Oh wow. That's embarassing. I used a named import for the Hidden component. Thanks