# Error " Invariant violation : Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am new to Unit testing. I am trying to run a test but I keep getting the following error :

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
I ran with { import Headers } and without {} and I keep getting the same error.

This is the current test.

```
 import React from 'react';
import { Headers } from './Headers';
import { configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import  * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Headers', () => {

let tree;
let baseProps;
let mockauthKeyValues;
let mockheaderKeyValues = {
    type: "TEST1",
    defaultData : "test",
};
let mockaddNewKeyValue;

 beforeEach(() => {
    baseProps = { // assing all of the props into MOCK
        authKeyValues: mockauthKeyValues,
       headerKeyValues: mockheaderKeyValues,
       addNewKeyValue: mockaddNewKeyValue
    }
})

 it ('should render without a authkeyvalues',() => {
baseProps = {
    ...baseProps,
    authKeyValues: {},
    };
    tree = renderer.create(<Headers {...baseProps } />)
    let treeJson = tree.toJSON();
    expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
    tree.unmount()
});

 it ('should render without headerKeyValues',() => {
baseProps = {
    ...baseProps,
    headerKeyValues: {},
};
    tree = renderer.create(<Headers {...baseProps } />)
    let treeJson = tree.toJSON();
    expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
    tree.unmount()
});

it ('should render without addNewKeyValue',() => {
baseProps = {
    ...baseProps,
    addNewKeyValue: {},
};
    tree = renderer.create(<Headers {...baseProps } />)
    let treeJson = tree.toJSON();
    expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
    tree.unmount()
});


 it('should render with all of the props', () => {  
    tree = renderer.create(<Headers {...baseProps} />)
    let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
    expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
    tree.unmount()
});
```

});

Headers.js

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import KeyValue from '../Utils/KeyValuePair'
const shortid = require('shortid')

export class Headers extends Component {

componentDidMount () {
if (this.props.authKeyValues == null) {
  this.setState({
    useDefaultData: false
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    useDefaultData: true
  })
}
}

generateKeyValues = () => {
 if (this.props.headerKeyValues == null) {
  return (
    <KeyValue
      id={shortid.generate()}
      type='headers'
      addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
    />
  )
} else {
 let defaultKeyValues = Object.keys(this.props.headerKeyValues).map((headerKey, idx) => {
    return (
      <KeyValue
        key={headerKey}
        id={headerKey}
        type={this.props.headerKeyValues[headerKey].type}
        addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
        defaultData={this.props.headerKeyValues[headerKey]}
      />
    )
  })
  defaultKeyValues.push(
    <KeyValue
      id={shortid.generate()}
      type='headers'
      addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
    />
  )
  return defaultKeyValues
}
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.generateKeyValues()}
    </div>
    )
 }
}
```

I expected the test to pass by getting all the props called correct.

Comment: How are you exporting the component?

Comment: export class FilterList extends Component {

Comment: Use `export default class ...`

Comment: I still get the same error.  I checked that also as well

Comment: Can you post the FilterList component code, please?

Comment: @Rupert , its a big file. Wont be able to post it here

Comment: Something is wrong with the way you're are exporting your component. Can you at least post the component without the big content inside the class? I.e post all of the imports at the top, then the line where the component starts and the ending brackets?

Comment: I added part of the code - I believe I might be calling the props wrong,  maybe writing extra code based on render() .

Comment: @Rupert check out the FileList.js

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions and it depends on the environment that you use. So , I will recommend you to read this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332 and this
[Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

one suggestion :

`downgrade native-base`

or:

`export default App;`

or :
instead of using

`export default App;`

use

`module.exports = App;`

Comment: I already checked the previous stackoverflow link but no success.

Comment: @user91 try one the solution that I provided above.

Comment: I found also this Open `App.js` file and modify this line
`class YourApp extends Component {` into
`export default class YourApp extends Component<{}> {`

Comment: I did it already, that's how it was at the beginning . but still having problems