# How to solve Element type is invalid error in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error while trying to add a Form Control for input from material ui, and the same error happens while trying to add Table component from material ui.

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

    Check the render method of `FormControl`.
        at invariant (invariant.js:42)
        at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:5753)
        at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:7531)
        at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7635)
        at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7756)
        at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
        at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7881)
        at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7850)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8225)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
```

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)