# How to add React-Bootstrap collapse functionality to Ant-Design <List> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, antd

I want to add a collapse effect to my list when I click my edit button so a body appears below my list element for input fields to edit the object. I am using react-bootstrap for the Collapse and ant-d for list.

Here is my List:

```
<List
  dataSource={this.state.data}
  renderItem={item => (
    <List.Item key={item.id} actions = {
       [
        <Button type="primary"  onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !open })}
           aria-controls="example-fade-text"
           aria-expanded={open} >
             Edit
            </Button>,
            <Button type="primary">
              Add to cart
          </Button>
        ]
      }>
          <List.Item.Meta
           avatar={<Avatar src={icon} size={64} />}
           title={item.name}
           description={item.description}
       />
      <div>Content</div>
      <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
         <div id="example-collapse-text">
            here's some text
         </div>
      </Collapse>
    </List.Item>
  )}
>
```

### This is the error I receive:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Context.Consumer` (I did not make this file, most likely auto generated by react).

```
  29 |   axios.get(DataUrl).then(
  30 |     res => {
  31 |       const apiData = res.data;
> 32 |       this.setState({data: apiData})
     | ^  33 |     }
  34 |   )
  35 | }
```

---

These are the contents of my state:

```
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    hasMore: true,
    open: false,
  }
```

and I have `const { open } = this.state.open` inside my render function. 
Related notes: I have the entire thing wrapped around InfiniteScroll ,but that shouldn't affect it, (I think).

My fetchData axios call works perfectly fine when I do not have Collapse used so I don't know why it's causing this issue.

Comment: there could be an error when you are either exporting or importing this component, please check the export and require()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string

Comment: I'm fairly certain my export/import is correct as it works completely normally when I exclude the lines 
<Collapse in={this.state.open}>
         <div id="example-collapse-text">
            here's some text
         </div>
      </Collapse>

Comment: Have you used react-bootstrap else where in your project ? .. How are you importing collapse in this component ?.....Looks like they don't have collapse component directly and they are using under accordion.. Check there components https://5c507d49471426000887a6a7--react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/alerts/

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing collapse from react-bootstrap in your component?
Probably this may sort out your issue.

If you would like to use Collapse from ant design. Then i made a sample code with your requirements.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mo4w7q85n8

Comment: Ok it turns out I imported it wrong I did import  {Collapse} instead of import Collapse.  However, when it runs, the edit button does nothing and the Collapse text appears right next to <div>Content</div>. Did I place my Collapse element in the right place? Also I checked out your codesandbox link. Which part of the code do you use Collapse from antd? Or am I supposed to add it. Thank you