# How to import Bootstrap components in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate checkboxes from `bootstrap` or `reactstrap` in React. I'm getting a common error, looked into [relevant posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string), still cannot figure it out. How do I fix this error:

> Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

#### Source of Error

The problem should be here in these two lines, which I'm not sure what it is.

```
import { InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText } from 'reactstrap';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';
```

If we'd remove these lines and the HTML copied below, it does not give any Error.

#### HTML

```
          <div>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Checkbox aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" />
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Text input with checkbox" />
            </InputGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Radio aria-label="Radio button for following text input" />
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Text input with radio button" />
            </InputGroup>
          </div>
```

#### [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rubin-620n1)

[Thanks! I'm new to React.]

Comment: removing all references to `FormControl` from your sandbox still gives me the same error.  are you sure the error corresponds to that import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepend` is one value of the `addonType` prop of InputGroupAddOn or InputGroupButton.  it's not a property of the `InputGroup` import.  `InputGroup.Prepend` is undefined, which is why React is complaining.

according to [the reactstrap docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/input-group/), you want this:

```
InputGroupAddOn.propTypes = {
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  addonType: PropTypes.oneOf(['prepend', 'append']).isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string
};

InputGroupButton.propTypes = {
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  addonType: PropTypes.oneOf(['prepend', 'append']).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  groupClassName: PropTypes.string, // only used in shorthand
  groupAttributes: PropTypes.object, // only used in shorthand
  className: PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component you camelcase `inputGroupAddOn` when declaring the prop types. When you imported it you didn't camel case the add on part, you're importing `InputGroupAddon`. That might be another issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

The Latest version of **reactstrap** doesn't support the use of `InputGroupAddon`. Use it directly from bootstrap.

```js
<div className="input-group-append">
  <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Search</span>
</div>
```