# Console error that I cannot find the solution to

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I continue to get the error below in the console. I have tried implicitly returning these components, setting them as both named AND default exports and also imported them as so. Any suggestions or input would be greatly appreciated.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
> Check the render method of 'Header'

**AppRouter Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import AboutPage from '../components/AboutPage';
import ContactPage from '../components/ContactPage';
import ErrorPage from '../components/ErrorPage';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import HomePage from '../components/HomePage';

const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter> 
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' component={HomePage} exact={true}/>
                <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage}/>
                <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage}/>
                <Route component={ErrorPage}/>
            </Switch>    
        </div>   
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

**Header Component:**

````
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>FRD</h1>
        <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='is-active' exact={true}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeClassName='is-active'>About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/contact' activeClassName='is-active'>Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
);

export default Header;```
````

Comment: Does this solves your problem   
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string

Comment: I also tried that before posting! It doesn't seem to matter which import I use, default or named.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Header component like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>FRD</h1>
        <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='is-active' exact={true}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeClassName='is-active'>About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/contact' activeClassName='is-active'>Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
);
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: I tried that just before I posted this - still the same error!

Edit: tried again just to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Have a good read of classes and how they function but also components first.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components
and
https://medium.com/@leannezhang/curly-braces-versus-parenthesis-in-reactjs-4d3ffd33128f
and then you shall understand what is going on.

```
    const Header = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>FRD</h1>
        <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='is-active' exact={true}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeClassName='is-active'>About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/contact' activeClassName='is-active'>Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

```
const Header = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>FRD</h1>
        <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='is-active' exact={true}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeClassName='is-active'>About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/contact' activeClassName='is-active'>Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
);
```

to

```
function Header() {
  return (  
      <div>
          <h1>FRD</h1>
          <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='is-active' exact={true}>Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/about' activeClassName='is-active'>About</NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/contact' activeClassName='is-active'>Contact</NavLink>
      </div>);
}
```

or alternatively, in AppRouter try the following.

```
<BrowserRouter> 
        <div>
            {Header}
            <Switch>
....
```

Comment: Neither seem to do the trick. My hair is beginning to be pulled out.

Comment: If you rename it from Header to something that is not in use. (Since it’s the default export you can can rename only the name when importing, but I’d try to rename it all the way)