# Importing Component Causes "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a ..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I created a custom component for Gatsby. I'm just trying to test out some very basic functionality.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

export default function Test() {
    return <div>Hello World form Test()</div>
}
```

I uploaded the component as a package to NPM and am trying to import it into a Gatsby site. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I'm importing the component like:

```js
import Test from "gatsby-theme-thepighero"
```

This makes me believe that I'm close to solving, but I cannot seem to navigate to my component the correct way. The component is located inside of the /src/components folder in a file called test.js.

I've also looked at other issues posted here such as [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) without much luck.

**EDIT: I've cleaned up the question based on a comment below.**

Answer (score 2):

If you are exporting a component as a `default`, you don't need the curly braces in the import statement.

```
export default function Test() {
    return "Hello World form Test()"
}
```

Must be imported as:

```
import Test from "gatsby-theme-thepighero"
```

Regarding your issue, try wrapping your component in a `div` or inside an empty fragment:

```
export default function Test() {
    return <div>Hello World form Test()</div> // or <>Hello World form Test()</>
}
```

Comment: I didn't think I needed the curly braces. I have tried wrapping the component inside a `div` with the same error.

Comment: I actually thought the same thing @ferran. When I went to post my answer I added a snippet and discovered that returning a string actually did work just fine.

Comment: So any ideas? Seems weird to me that this isn't working.

Comment: It has to be related with the routing of `gatsby-theme-thepighe` but I'm afraid I can't debut it more without a repo or sandbox

Comment: https://github.com/ThePigHero/gatsby-theme-thepighero

Comment: Use this as a sample: https://github.com/UNDataForum/gatsby-themes

Comment: @FerranBuireu What specifically should I be looking at?

Comment: The folder structure and the importation

Comment: @FerranBuireu I must be missing something obvious because I still cannot get it working once I change the folder structure. I actually receive an error saying that the "path" argument must be of type string and that it's undefined. I'll continue to dig.