# React Error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to find the answer via similar questions but haven't been able to get this resolved.

When I run a react app, I get the following error:

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.**

My index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { AppProvider } from './context'
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
    <App />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

And my App.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// import pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import SingleCocktail from "./pages/SingleCocktail";
import Error from "./pages/Error";
// import components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cocktail/:id">
          <SingleCocktail />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <Error />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I originally had issues with the imports which I was able to resolve but I'm lost.

Any points on what to look at would be great, thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: @rsmeral - unfortunately not, tried both ways and got two different errors. So when I wrap the app import in curly brackets import { App } from './App', I get the following error:

./src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'App' is not exported from './App'.

Comment: Check all your other components `Home`, `About`, `SingleCocktail`, ... – the problem is most likely there. Make sure they all `export default`, if you want to import them like you do (`import Home from ...`).

Comment: Found the issue - it was related to my home.js script - it needed a slight tweak but the browser error sent me in a completely different direction, thanks for you time @rsmeral

Comment: _"it needed a slight tweak"_ – can you please describe it for future readers?