# Optimized Way To Initialized Firebase in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

During building an app, I couldn't be able to initialized firebase `V9` in optimized form in expo react native. I switch from `V8` to `V9` And counter different error, which aren't making sense to me.

Like `module idb missing from file "...\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\...` even I create a **metro.config.js** File.

And `Firebase could not be found within the project` when it is present in (Firebase V8).

And this error, idk what's that about  `at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in register`.
`Error at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl....` , here's the [issue](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/3533) or check this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783101/in-react-native-app-i-got-the-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

And `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.apps')`.

All such questions and their answers are available on stackoverflow. But none of them work for me. And Im not elaborating these issues, just giving you idea. So I try some things, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In above question, I tell about some errors and after many searching I was able to fixed my problem.

First, I delete `.expo` , `.expo-share` , `node_modules` , `package-lock.json` , and `yarn.lock` (if you have). Then `yarn install` or `npm install`.

Second, change the firebase code to this **for V9**. As I see many people suggesting to downgrade to **V8** when above mentioned errors occurs when they don't need to.

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
// import others as you need

const firebaseConfig = { ... };

let app;

if (getApps().length === 0) app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
else app = getApp();

const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();

export { auth, db };
```

For **V8**

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
// import others as you need

const firebaseConfig = { ... };

let app;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
else app = firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth, db };
```

I mentioned about creating a **metro.config.js**, as I read comments in this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179070/react-native-bundling-failure-error-message-while-trying-to-resolve-module-i), some are confusing is there problem related to firebase or metro file. For me, I guess its firebase. If still you get this error, then downgrade your to firebase@9.6.11, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181480/17973320)

I give reference of 2 errors, and other 2 are easily available. It work for me, I hope this will help anyone of you.