# React-select library crashing my page on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-select

I am currently attempting to implement react-select into a web-app I am developing, but whenever it is rendered it crashes the entire react application with minified error #130 - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

The code which procedurally generates these select elements looks as such

```
let optionObjects = await retrievePropertyOptions(null, null, null, property, true)
                    let options = this.listOptionConstructor(optionObjects, true)
                    //options returns an array of objects with value and label properties
                    let selector =
                        <React.Fragment key={number}>
                            <label className="cssclasses"
                                for={`select-custom-${name}`}>
                                {name}</label>
                            <ReactSelect options={options} onChange={(selected) => {
                                this.setState({
                                    [`multi-selector${number}`]: selected
                                })}}
                                value = {this.state[`multi-selector${number}`]}
                             />
                        </React.Fragment>
```

And my import is simply `const ReactSelect = require('react-select')`

Does anyone know why I am running into this error? It works perfectly with everything besides the react-select component so I am very confused what I may have done wrong. I tried the import as a de-structured object as well just in case and still ran into the same issue. When I console.log out selector, I get an object that looks identical to any other react fragment object, and I am bundling my files using webpack which I believe is correctly configured as it builds and works perfectly besides this one issue. Any suggestions are appreciated.

edit: Created a codepen to showcase the issue (https://codepen.io/AugustTGuenther/pen/abmJEpx), getting a different error here and slightly more description from the react error but still does not want to render even with static mock data as the options. I imagine if someone could point out what I am doing wrong there it would be the same issue in my actual code - matched react versions and react-select versions to the actual code as well.

Comment: Try to console the options variable you should have data in object which will have key-value pair in string.

Comment: @MohdFaizan_06 my options object looks as such
[
    {
        "value": "16",
        "label": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "value": "15",
        "label": "Firefox"
    },
    {
        "value": "14",
        "label": "Internet Explorer"
    },
    {
        "value": "17",
        "label": "Safari"
    }
]

Comment: What is a value of 'name' variable inside label?

Comment: @AndreySmolko It is just a reference to a static object in the actual code - i genericized it for this. That is certainly not the problem as when i leave that label in place but comment out the ReactSelect element it renders the label properly and does not crash my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being webpack/babel messing up default exports/imports, see jackypan1989's answer on this question (not the "accepted" answer): [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Had nothing to do with react-select in particular - they just happened to be the react component library I was using which got broken.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code snippet where the data fetching is done in an useEffect and then the value is set to state and passed in options of the react-select. It should mostly be an issue with the options that is been created. It would also be nice if you could move the data fetching logic the useEffect hook.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

// mockData is just a mock.It should be coming from the server.
const mockData = [
  { value: 'some value', label: 'some label 1 ' },
  { value: 'some value', label: 'some label 2' },
  { value: 'some value', label: 'some label 3' },
];

export default function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState([]);
  const retrievePropertyOptions = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(mockData);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getProperties() {
      const result = (await retrievePropertyOptions()) as any;
      setResponse(result);
    }
    getProperties();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactSelect options={response} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar thing but with just hardcoded mockData in that format and it still crashes  even when all the rest of the config (onChange / value) is omitted.