# Error "Element type is invalid" React component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Many times I've seen this error, and honestly I never know how to fix it, or how i fixed it in the past ...

`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here's my component implementation, I'm trying to understand what's wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SvgFromUri } from 'react-native-svg';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { AppColors } from '../constants';

const imgSize = 55;

const CompanyIcon = ({ url }) => {

    return (
        <>
            {
                url && !url.includes('favicon')
                    ? <SvgFromUri uri={url} width={imgSize} height={imgSize} onError={console.error} />
                    : <Image source={require('../assets/app_icon48.png')} style={
                        {
                            borderWidth: 1, 
                            borderColor: AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE, 
                            borderRadius: 4,
                            width: imgSize,
                            height: imgSize
                        }
                    } />
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default CompanyIcon;
```

Thanks so much for any help community

The options I found research about it said something about exporting the component as default, so I did, but no success :(

---

Update:
Looks like it's a bug within the svg component :|
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/1742

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: Please check around `AppColors` or `AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE`, because the error said about the "expected a string". I guess the error may come from either of them.

It could be the `AppColors`'s import (default or named imports), or the value of `AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

check your exports, if you have a default export you should import like this :

```
import FunctionName from '../location'; // without {}
```

or maybe you

> forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports