# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object problem in React

Tags: reactjs

The error message continues with

"Check the render method of `ProductDetail`."

And this page was working actually in the begginings then I made some changes in project for make work the debugging mode because it wasn't working in vs code.

I added

```
     "type": "module"
```

into my `package.json`

And after that I deleted all

```
 require()
```

and turned them into

```
 import
```

After that it warned me to change my `import` paths and add `.js` to end and I did that. After those changes I checked the page and it gave me that error.

My `ProductDetail` page is:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchProduct } from "../../api.js";
import { Box, Text, Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import moment from "moment";

function ProductDetail() {
  const { product_id } = useParams();

  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["product", product_id],
    queryFn: () => fetchProduct(product_id),
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <div>Error.</div>;
  }

  const images = data.photos.map((url) => ({ original: url }));

  return (
    <div>
      <Button colorScheme="pink">Add to Basket</Button>
      <Text as="h2" fontSize="2x1">
        {data.title}
      </Text>
      <Text as="h2" fontSize="2x1">
        {moment(data.createdAt).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
      </Text>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <Box margin="10">
        <ImageGallery items={images} />
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

I checked this [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

but didn't solve my problems or I missed something.

Comment: What is the value of `data.title` or `data.description` or `moment(data.createdAt).format("DD/MM/YYYY")` that is rendered? Try narrowing down where the issue occurs by commenting out all the JSX except for the `div` and try running the app, if the error went away then uncomment ***one*** component/element at-a-time and re-run the app to test until the error reproduces. Once you find the component/element triggering the issue repeat this process in *that* component/element until you find the exact invalid JSX value reference.

Comment: I published the problem as an Answer down there. The problem is "<ImageGallery items={images} />" line when I deleted it. It didn't give me the error again but why it happened couldn't get it.

Comment: Is the `react-image-gallery` project dependency properly installed?

Comment: Yes, it is. I uninstalled and installed it again but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. The problem was the `"type":"module"` property in my `package.json` when I deleted it error was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is about

```
<ImageGallery items={images} />
```

When I deleted it, it didn't give any error but I didn't understand why it happened exactly.

The problem is

```
   "type":"module"
```

in my `package.json` when I deleted it problem ended.